# Selection windows html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website (html/css/javascript) that works like a restaurant assistant, i.e. the user can order food, pay for the meal, call the waiter, etc... and i had to create all these "menus", like for example to order food you click on the "menu" button and the menu shows up, when you're done it hides. For this i'm just changing the display attribute with javascript but for each window and each button i have to make a new function to handle the visibility and the amount of functions i have by now it's just too much, is there any other simpler way of making these menu windows (without making different pages)? Thanks.

```
    //open menu 1
    document.getElementById('menu1').addEventListener('click', function(){
        changeDisplay('menubutton','menu1');
    });

    //close menu 1
    document.getElementById('menu1').addEventListener('click', function(){
        changeDisplay('menu1','menubutton');
    });

    //open menu 2
    document.getElementById('menu2').addEventListener('click', function(){
        changeDisplay('menubutton2','menu2');

    function changeDisplay(id1, id2) {
        document.getElementById(id1).style.display = "flex";
        document.getElementById(id2).style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: You may supply a short excerpt from your code to better clarify your issue.

Comment: This is quite a broad topic. Can you narrow it down or reduce the scope of the question?

Comment: Short answer: reusable code should be split out and kept in own library (e.g. utils), whole UI should be split into components/modules and you keep event handlers inside each component file. Take insight from how popular UI libraries organize code (React, Polymer). I think the pattern is called [PAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation%E2%80%93abstraction%E2%80%93control).

Answer (score 1):

You may automate the process by using dom selectors and ([data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes))attributes.

```js
const openers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-openMenuNumber]'));

openers.forEach(function(opener){
  opener.onclick = () => {

    document.querySelector('.show').classList.remove('show');
    const num = opener.dataset.openmenunumber;
    document.getElementById(`menu${num}`).classList.add('show');

  }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu1" class="menu show">
  I'm menu1:<button data-openMenuNumber="2">open2</button>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="menu">
  I'm menu2:<button data-openMenuNumber="1">open1</button>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbByvL

Comment: that helps, it's still through display but a lot simple.

Comment: In some cases you'll better to use `.off { display: none }` class instead of `.show`, because you may need custom values for `display` (not just `initial`), but then it will require slightly more code. Just ask if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple function like this:

```
function showItem(itemName){
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, function(item){
    item.style.display = "none";
  });
  document.getElementById(itemName).style.display = "block";
}
```

Working Example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjKXLj